# Sub-Queries in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, database, syntax, subquery, sybase

We have an application which indexes data using user-written SQL statements. We place those statements within parenthesis so we can limit that query to a certain criteria. For example:

```
select * from (select F_Name from table_1)q where ID > 25
```

Though we have discovered that this format does not function using a Sybase database. Reporting a syntax error around the parenthesis. I've tried playing around on a test instance but haven't been able to find a way to achieve this result. I'm not directly involved in the development and my SQL knowledge is limited. I'm assuming the 'q' is to give the subresult an alias for the application to use.

Does Sybase have a specific syntax? If so, how could this query be adapted for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of SYBASE database do you use? ASE, IQ, Anywhere? SYBASE is a company not db system. Your query works on ASE.

Comment: In most cases, you can just use standard `JOIN`s instead of `FROM` subqueries.

Comment: In other cases, you often use temporary tables (`#tablename`) to hold the result of the subquery for use in the next query.

Comment: Apart from the case sensitive issues that others reported, the query `select * from (select F_Name from table_1)q where ID > 25` should not work in any DBMS. The derived table `q` has only one column (`F_Name`) and does not have a column named `ID`. So, it should throw an error about `q` and `ID` in all DBMS I can think of.

Comment: I will look to provide more information, I wasn't aware there were various versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE is case sensitive w.r.t. all identifiers and the query shall work:

as per @HannoBinder query :

`select id from ...` is not the same as `select ID from...` so make sure of the case.

Also make sure that the column `ID` is returned by the `Q` query in order to be used in where clause .

If the table and column names are in Upper case the following query shall work:

`select * from (select F_NAME, ID from TABLE_1) Q where ID > 25`

Comment: "SYBASE does not support column or table names in lower case" - Sybase ASE is case sensitive w.r.t. all identifiers.

Comment: @HannoBinder: you mean case **in** - sensitive, right?

Comment: And edit your query to reflect what you say, like `select F_NAME from (select ID, F_NAME from TABLE_1) Q where Q.ID > 25`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, I mean case *sensitive*, `select id from ...` is not the same as `select ID from...`.

Comment: @HannoBinder I made this clear with the ID note... Thanks guys :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It appears that ASE is *by default* case sensitive, but can be configured to be in-sensitive.